# Inconsistency in Python sqlite3's REAL precision

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, precision

If I insert floating point values (`REAL`s) in [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) in Python 3.7, the values that end up in the actual database are different if I use different methods to do so. Shouldn't they be the same? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug/feature?

```py
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as c:
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value REAL)')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, ?)', [2.7391304969787598])
    c.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (2,       2.7391304969787598)')
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM test'):
        print(row)
```

produces the output

```
(1, 2.7391304969787598)
(2, 2.73913049697876)
```

Comment: It works correctly for me (both numbers are the same - tested on python 3.4 and 3.7, sqlite3 version = 2.6.0). What is your sqlite3 version?

Comment: `sqlite3.version` 2.6.0 and `sqlite3.sqlite_version` 3.21.0

Comment: So, I was not able to reproduce your results (and even your configuration).
python3.6 sqlite_version 3.21 -> OK
python3.7 sqlite_version 3.24 -> OK (no lower version available in conda)

Comment: I upgraded Python and I still get the same result. `sqlite3.version` 2.6.0 and `sqlite3.sqlite_version` 3.31.1.
`Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm on linux and do not have access to windows box. So I'm not able to help you further.